# Header of my website get disappeared

Tags: magento2, theme, header, porto

I am working on a magento2 website using a smartwave Porto theme, suddenly I noticed that the cart icon and search bar disappeared and my menu get disorganized and unclickable. I have run the following command but still not working.

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
but all not working

can anyone help, here is the website https://micserah.com

Comment: Do you have a before/after image to compare? Normally when the top menu breaks it points to a varnish configuration issue. I can’t see “<esi:include” in the source but that doesn’t necessarily mean that this isn’t the issue. I can also see the “X-Magento-Tags” header so I’m guessing the site is in developer mode? Are you using varnish at all?

Comment: Thanks @Craig, yes i'm using varnish cache

Comment: @Craig yes the site is in developer mode

Answer (score 0):

run below commands and check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US -f 
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

if cache enabled on server or cpanel then please try to flush cache on that too.

Comment: i have tried above command but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Looking your website, seems that you have missed important code lines in homepage (hiding or deleting). I see a lot of comments within <!-->. Opening or closing them in a wrong code line, may damage your homepage. Inspecting the source of your page, I was able to see that the menu still works at collection pages, such as:

https://micserah.com/womens/collections/all-watches.html

It missed the format, but is there, working. I couldn't find the shopping cart.
The best would recover a most recent backup if you have it or upload basic files for your Porto Theme, such as index.php styles etc.

Please remember to backup your files before doing any change.

general comment: sorry to review this, but the plural of Man and Woman is Men and Women, not Mens and Womens.